# How to convert a 15 char Id in Lightning ($SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, id, casting, id-comparison

I'm using `$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id` to find out if the current User is the owner of the current record. The issue here is that the method is providing a 15 char user Id.

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.record.OwnerId == $SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id}">
```

results in `false` since these are the values:

> "0050R0000013XhlQAE"
>
> "0050R0000013Xhl"

Is there any easy way to cast it right there to a 18 digit? Or any other workaround so I don't have to do another server trip?

### UPDATE:

Salesforce fixed this with winter'19.

```
$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id
```

does now return 18 chars.

Comment: That sounds like a bug. I would rather report this to salesforce than try to work around it. You should always be getting an 18-character ID.

Comment: Nasty bug, had to do a workaround for our custom filters due to this. It is so inconsistent with apex's UserInfo.getUserId() counterpart.

Comment: @sfdcfox good news, it's already fixed in winter'19 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to get the `OwnerId` as 15 digits, you can do the truncation wherever you set `record` in your controller. You can either overwrite `record.OwnerId`, or store a separate `recordOwnerId` attribute. I would probably do the latter.

```
// somewhere wiithin your controller
component.set("v.record", someRecordData);
component.set("v.recordOwnerId", someRecordData.OwnerId.substring(0, 15));
```

And then you could compare:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.recordOwnerId == $SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id}">
```

---

Or if you really want, you could create a formula to explicitly store the 15 digit OwnerId:

```
LEFT(OwnerId, 15)
```

And then you would compare to this value instead:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.record.Owner_Id_15_Digit__c == $SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id}">
```

Comment: well the owner is in 18 chars already, the problem is the user (it comes with 15, don't ask me why :P)

Comment: So you could just truncate in your controller wherever you retrieve `record`, no?

Comment: lightning data service.. But yes, I guess this is my way to go. pretty hacky though :( Actually I will just prepare a boolean in js..

Comment: Funny, they already fixed this with winter 19 but my scratch org was still on summer...

Answer (score 1):

Another way is you can also create a method in lightning component which will convert 15 to 18 digit

component.cmp

```
<aura:attribute name="currentUserID" type="String"
default="{!($SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id)}" access="global" />

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.recordOwnerId == currentUserID}">
```

controller:

```
convertTo18 : function(component) {
        var idParts = component.get("v.currentUserID").match(/(.{5})(.{5})(.{5})/)
        var base36 = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'.split('')
        var output = []
        var outer, inner, subparts, buffer

        for(outer = 1; outer <= 3; outer++) {
            subparts = idParts[outer].split('')
            buffer = 0
            for(inner = 4; inner >= 0; inner--) {
                buffer = (buffer << 1) | (subparts[inner].match(/[A-Z]/) ? 1 : 0)
            }
            output.push(base36[buffer])
        }

        component.set("v.currentUserID",component.get("v.currentUserID") + output.join(''));
    }
```

ref: [convert 15 digit Id to 18 digit Id](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133707/convert-15-digit-id-to-18-digit-id)